# BouncyCastle - GPG. Extract Public Key from Secret Key

Tags: java, bouncycastle, gnupg

I'm using this java code to extract the public key from secret key:

```
PGPSecretKeyRingCollection ring = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(decoderStream,
            new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());
Iterator<PGPSecretKeyRing> it = ring.getKeyRings();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    PGPSecretKeyRing key = it.next();
    Iterator<PGPPublicKey> itpublic = key.getPublicKeys();
    while (itpublic.hasNext()) {
        PGPPublicKey pubKey = itpublic.next();
        // use this pubKey
    }
}
```

If I try to export that key in an ArmoredOutputStream, I get something like:

```
    -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
    Version: BCPG v1.66
    
    hQEMA6GfAr1vmvVrAQf/XF/6DqSxZu0dXXVnhfxoot+YTLBrwnec/af72R8G1aJI
    [...]
    =eLkg
    -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

If I use this key to encrypt something from java code, everything works fine.

If I use this key to encrypt files from command line (or other clients like Kleopatra):

```
$ gpg --import pubKey.gpg
$ gpg --encrypt ...
```

I get the "Unusable public key" error.

Am I doing something wrong with the public key export from java code?

Comment: I don't know how this relate to your particular issue, but in general the whole idea of asymetric cryptography is to generate pair of keys, that have this property, that you can NOT generate one from the other.

Comment: With a GPG client, you can import the secret key and then export a public key from that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use all the PublicKeyRing, not only the master public key:

```
List<PGPPublicKey> list = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<PGPSecretKeyRing> it = ring.getKeyRings();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    PGPSecretKeyRing secretRing = it.next();
    Iterator<PGPPublicKey> itpublic = secretRing.getPublicKeys();
    while (itpublic.hasNext()) {
        PGPPublicKey pub = itpublic.next();
        list.add(pub);
    }
    Iterator<PGPPublicKey> itextrapublic = secretRing.getExtraPublicKeys();
    while (itextrapublic.hasNext()) {
        PGPPublicKey pub = itextrapublic.next();
        list.add(pub);
    }
}
PGPPublicKeyRing publicRing = new PGPPublicKeyRing(list);
publicRing.encode(armoredOutputStream)
```